# Como insertar dos o mas productos de un carrito en base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

solicito de su valiosa ayuda para poder resolver un "problemita", tengo un carrito de compras el cual si logra insertar en una base de datos el registro de una orden con un producto seleccionado con precio e imagen.

```
        $db_query = "INSERT INTO pedidos(productName, orderNumber, productPrice, PriceUnit, currency, Image) VALUES (:productName, :orderNumber, :productPrice, :PriceUnit, :currency, :Image)";

        $statement = $conexion->prepare($db_query);
        $statement->bindParam(':productName', $productName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':orderNumber', $orderNumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':productPrice', $productPrice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':PriceUnit', $PriceUnit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':currency', $currency, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':Image', $Image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
```

Hasta aquí todo va bien,,, el detalle está que cuando quiero insertar 2 productos o mas no logro hacerlo, lo que he hecho ha sido modificar esta parte del código, pero lo que logra hacer es un registro duplicado con los mismos valores,,, y no con los valores de cada producto.

```
        $db_query = "INSERT INTO pedidos(productName, orderNumber, productPrice, PriceUnit, currency, Image) VALUES (:productName, :orderNumber, :productPrice, :PriceUnit, :currency, :Image),
        (:productName, :orderNumber, :productPrice, :PriceUnit, :currency, :Image)";
```

Como puedo hacer para lograr insertar en la base de datos la lista de productos seleccionados con sus respectivos precios e imágenes?

De antemano Muchas Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan proporcionar.

Comment: Ricardo, el problema no parece ser la query... pero tampoco veo donde modificas el valor de la variable para el producto 1 y el producto 2. ¿Dónde se guardan los valores del producto dos? ¿Si los placers tienen el mismo nombre en tu consulta modificada como distingues entre producto 1 y producto 2?

Answer (score 0):

Primero creo que debes tener tus datos organizados correctamente, simplifico:

```
    $carrito[0] = array("productName"=>"Plumas", "productPrice"=>"37");
    $carrito[1] = array("productName"=>"Banderas", "productPrice"=>"74");
```

Utilizando (casi) tu consulta...

```
    //Consulta modificada
    $db_query = "INSERT INTO pedidos(productName, productPrice) VALUES (:productName0, :productPrice0), (:productName1, :productPrice1)";

    $statement = $conexion->prepare($db_query);
    $statement->bindParam(':productName0', $carrito[0]["productName"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':productPrice0', $carrito[0]["productPrice"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':productName1', $carrito[1]["productName"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':productPrice1', $carrito[1]["productPrice"], PDO::PARAM_STR)

    $statement->execute();
```

**A considerar:**
¿Estas seguro de que siempre vas a tener dos y sólo dos productos en el carrito?
¿No será mejor que tu consulta inserte sólo un producto y eso lo pongas dentro de un forEach para que lo haga para cada producto?

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias Alejandro,,, si ese es otro gran detalle que faltaria por solucionar,,, si llegan a ser mas de dos productos que quieran ordenar en el carrito,,, como hacer que se registren en la base de datos dos a mas productos? sin importar cuantos sean,, de nuevo, Gracias!

Comment: Usa un ciclo For y que la consulta sólo guarde un producto, así por cada producto haces una llamada y no te preocupas por cuantos productos metió el usuario